# Who is previewing tag wikis?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, preview

I'm not quite to 2500 rep on SU yet, so when I made a tag wiki for [VBA](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vba), it said that it would have to be previewed and approved.  That was quite a while back, and nothing's been done on it one way or the other.  Who is responsible for previewing tag wikis on SU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either users with a [reputation over 5000 or moderators can approve tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

You did [create the tag wiki body](https://superuser.com/posts/214387/revisions) but apparently left the excerpt blank.

Adding in the tag excerpt proper [fills the landing page](https://superuser.com/tags/vba/info).

Comment: I thought the excerpt was autogenerated from the first four lines of the wiki body.

Comment: It was previously for those already written. Now you have to separately input that chunk. @lan